# String array in java giving error

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments, android-resources

This code is working ok, But I want to initialize this list by using array from the resource file.

```
private String[] data = { "Selection 1", "Selection 2", "Selection 3" };
```

This code is from [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) link, but it is not working for me. It is inside fragment so I even added `getActivity()` before `getResources()` but still it is giving error. Error says that it is caused by inflating that fragment. And when I replace this line with above code snippet it works ok.

```
Resources res = getResources();
private String[] data = res.getStringArray(R.array.sort_by);
```

**Note:** This is inside baseAdapter and base adapter like I have given below and that baseadapter is inside my fragment.

```
    private SpinnerAdapter SortBySpinnerAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

    private TextView text;
    Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
    private String[] data = res.getStringArray(R.array.sort_by); 
    private int count = 2;
    ...
```

Comment: Please give the *exact* error. Is this a compile-time error? An exception at execution time?

Comment: Yawar, where exactly are you calling the getResources and getStringArray? Is this in the onCreate? A complete stacktrace of the error and some more code could help solving your problem.

Comment: Oops what a silly mistake I was doing, I forget that I have to initialize in onCreate, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Move the init part in the `OnCreate`

```
private SpinnerAdapter SortBySpinnerAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SortBySpinnerAdapter = new BaseAdapter()
    {
        private TextView text;
        Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
        private String[] data = res.getStringArray(R.array.sort_by);
        private int count = 2;
```

If you do the init out of the OnCreate, Activity is not yet created/available

Comment: No need to move whole adapter in onCreate, Just moving initialization of data variable solved my issue.